# Creating a cross table in R using subsets

Tags: r

I have this table:

[image: Table smoker]

Now I would like to create a cross table only for agecat younger, so it would look something like this:

/ alive / dead

1 / 372 / 46

0 / 393 / 25

I want to work with subsets to obtain the right data from the original table but I don't really know where to start, can someone help me out?

Comment: Please use `dput()` to present your data! image files are useless.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to R and also quite new to this website. I have no clue what dput() will do and how to use it. Also I don't see why this image is useless; I only posted it to clarify my question.

Comment: I looked at the possible duplicate but it's not the same. I want to work with subsets which they don't use there.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. And, have a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), please, There you will find an explanation of `dput()`. Thank you.

Comment: @Stan Please put the result of `dput(yourDataframe)` in your question. i.e. edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42886977/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
SmokersAlive <- subset(df, Smoker == 1)            #table showing only the smokers
SmokersAlive <- sum(subset(df, Smoker == 1)$Alive) #sum of col. "Alive" from table above
```

here the code you need:

```
SmokersAlive <- sum(subset(df, Smoker == 1)$Dead)

SmokersDead     <- 1 #sum(subset....) should stand here
NonSmokersAlive <- 1 #...
NonSmokersDead  <- 1

Overview <- data.frame(matrix(c(SmokersAlive, SmokersDead, NonSmokersAlive, NonSmokersDead), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))

colnames(Overview) <- c("alive","dead")
rownames(Overview) <- c("0","1")

Overview
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm going to try it out!

Comment: I used your second line to obtain 4 values, how do I present these 4 values in a table now?

Comment: I've edited my answer.  Now it should work like you wanted it to

Comment: Yeah this worked, thank you!